# saving outputs from a loop in Matlab in different folders

Tags: matlab, save

I am using the codes below which save the output images in the same directory as is the m-file. I am trying to automate to save the output images in different folders with the folder name same as the 'file' name.

```
 clear all;
 files = dir('*.dat');
 for k = 1:length(files);
     filename   = files(k).name;
     data1      = fopen(filename,'r');
     data2      = textscan(data1, '%f%f','headerlines',1,'CollectOutput',1);
     data       = data2{:,1};

     x = data(:,1);             
     y = data(:,2); 
     plot(x, y);  
     [pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(filename);  

     temp = ['fig', num2str(k), '.eps'];
     print(gcf, '-depsc', temp);
     fclose(data1);
 end
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: the way you have it, all of the files listed in the `datFiles` variable are file that are in the your local directory, so I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: yes, the datFiles (12.dat, 15.dat, 16.dat etc) are in the local directory. The output images are fig1, fig2, fig3, etc in the same local directory. I want to save fig1 in subfolder '12', fig2 in subfolder '15', fig3 in subfolder '16' and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a subfolder (named after your filename), then print in this folder.

```
folderName = filename;
mkdir(folderName);
print( gcf , [folderName '/' filename] ); %or use `filesep` function to replace /
```

Comment: I just made little modifications like this and it works fine for me:  folderName = name; mkdir(folderName); print(gcf, '-depsc', [foldername '/' temp]);